# A problem on summation of a finite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

While working with a definite integral, I came across the following series:

$$g_n(x)=\sum\limits_{0\leqslant k<n/2} (-1)^k {n \choose 2k+1} x^{n-(2k+1)}\\ = \frac{i}{2}[(x-i)^n-(x+i)^n] \tag{1}$$

Here, the values of k are integers less than n/2. For the first three values of n, the values of the function are as follows:

$g_1(x)=1 \\g_2(x)=2x \\g_3(x)=3x^2-1$

From the second form of the series in equation (1), it can be readily obtained that

$$g_n(x)=\frac{i}{2}[(x-i)^n-(x+i)^n]=(1+x^2)^{n/2} \sin(x\sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}})) \tag{2}$$

I have two questions as follows:

1. How is the second form of $g_n(x)$ obtained from the first form in equation (1)?
2. Is it possible to obtain the result in equation (2) directly from the first form of equation (1), i.e. without using the expression $\frac{i}{2}[(x-i)^n-(x+i)^n]$?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? the second form in equation (1) is much easier to handle and I see no point in not using it.

Comment: Actually I could not figure out how the second form of equation (1) is obtained.

Comment: Use the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $n=2m$ is even. Since $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$, note that $$(x-i)^n-(x+1)^n=((x-i)^m)^2-((x+i)^m)^2=(x-i)^m(x+i)^m=((x-i)(x+i))^m=(x^2+1)^m.$$ Now use that $$(a+b)^m=\sum\limits_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}a^nb^{m-k}$$ which yields for $b=x^2, a=1$ the formula $$(x^2+1)^m=\sum\limits_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}x^{2m-2k}.$$ Of course, since you are interested in $\frac{i}{2}((x-i)^n-(x+i)^n)$, you have to multiply the sum above by the factor $i/2$. Can you conclude?